# CImg: How to seperate the console and CImgDisplay window

Tags: c++, cimg

I want to write a small application that i can enter the order to console to control the CImgDisplay window to change. But when CImgDisplay window is open. The console can't do anything until i close the CImgDisplay window. How to deal with this problem?

Comment: Please give an example of what you mean by *"entering the order to console"*. Thank you.

Comment: Please also say what Operating System you use.